Source of a shloka relating to Gods being present in every part of the cow
Does anyone know the source of the following shloka?

प्रष्ठे ब्रह्मा गले विष्णुर्मुखे रुद्रः प्रतिष्ठितः |
मध्ये देवगणा: सर्वे रोमकूपे महर्षय: | |

